# How to convert integer (112 format) in to date using Dax formula?

Tags: date, integer, powerbi, dax, reporting

How to convert `integer` (112 format) in to `date` using **DAX** formula?

The date is in integer format `20170727` and I want to convert it to the following `27/07/2017`.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

= DATEVALUE(FORMAT(Date[DateKey], "0000/00/00"))

Answer (score 1):

One way to get this in pure DAX is:

```
=DATE(INT(LEFT([IntegerDate],4)),INT(MID([IntegerDate],5,2)),INT(RIGHT([IntegerDate],2)))
```

Replace `IntegerDate` by the actual name of your integer date.

However it is better perform this transformations using `PowerQuery` or a data integration tool of your preference.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are correct, but I think just partially. The full method:
The full porcess:

1. Right click on your table and select `New column`
2. On the top of your editor insert the following line:`YourColumnName=DATEVALUE('YourTable'[YourDateFieldINTEGER])`
3. You will got the default date/time format
4. On the top under `Modeling` you can change (and set as default) any date/time format.
   [image: ChangeDateFormat]

I suggest you to use the same date/time format in all field it is more clear, and easier if you don't have to convert always your dates.

I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new column and set its type to date.
The DAX for the new column I used is a variation of [alejandro zuleta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11928680/kesadae11) answer.

```
DateType = 
 IF('DW FactMeasurement PAC Daily Report'[DateKey] <> 0,
    (LEFT('DW FactMeasurement PAC Daily Report'[DateKey],4)) & "-"
    &(MID('DW FactMeasurement PAC Daily Report'[DateKey],5,2))& "-"
    &(RIGHT('DW FactMeasurement PAC Daily Report'[DateKey],2))
  )
```